# What db backend to use for ~60,000 static records

Tags: java, python, xml, rdbms

i am not an expert programmer :D

well i had built an application an year ago in vb which usually deals with querying the data, process it and display in a list box. Initially i did not have any idea on databases, so i had done it with files :)

After few months i altered it(uses ms access database)

well thats story about a year ago. recently i learnt java, python. so very crazy abt java. well python is also superb, but i love to code in java. so ive decided to re-code the application again with some additional features using java.

The application will query the database as the user types something in a textbox and processes n displays the resulting query in a listbox.

conceptually the database will have only one table. The database will contain approximately 60,000 records. each record will have three fields, two of type String, other one is a unique number. occasionally there will be insertion of records, say monthly 500 records or so. never alter existing data.

So this is the situation..

The question is - what do i choose for database? is ms-access good for this?? what about xml? what are other good options best suited for above situation??
some say rdbms is not good for several reasons, should i not go with rdbms??

Comment: Your question title could use some rephrasing, to better fit the question.

Comment: Downvoters, please remember to write what is wrong with the question, especially for new users. For this one, I'm wondering as well, except for a badly chosen title.

Comment: Go with Derby, which is a relational database distributed with Java.  You won't have to install anything.  See the [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html).

Comment: I made a new less provocative title for you. Change it if you don't like it. :)

Comment: @user846585 - Yours is a valid question (I nominated for reopening) but sloppily formulated: poor title, lot's of idioms, SMS-style abbreviations, and syntax mistakes. Word of advice: do care about the formulation of your questions. You might be a nice person, but other SO users only know you through your questions and lack of care in formulation is often perceived like lack of care for others.

Comment: It's a valid question yet, still, arguably not appropriate for SO. Open-ended requests for advice/recommendations are generally discouraged (but perhaps would be appropriate on programmers.SE?).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/). It is an embedded database that could be a good solution for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with a SQL database, they're easy to set up and JDBC is very easy to use. XML would be really bad for that amount of data.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends how much money you want to despend in your project. 
Java is open, also you have good options to work with java, there are:

mySql
Postgres

if you want you can also use SQL Server (Microsoft) and Oracle (work perfect with java).

It all depends of you.

But listen to my advice, do not go to work with MS Access, its a big trouble. Forget. If want to choose into microsoft products, then SQL Server is a good option.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you try python, look at [tablib](http://docs.python-tablib.org/en/latest/).

> Tablib is an MIT Licensed format-agnostic tabular dataset library,
>   written in Python. It allows you to import, export, and manipulate
>   tabular data sets. Advanced features include, segregation, dynamic
>   columns, tags & filtering, and seamless format import & export.

Tablib is a good alternative for simple, one-table databases as yours and you can import/export the data from/to many different formats (csv, xlsx, json, yaml).